# How can I use pop ups for Hotspot images instead of Tool tip

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, design-patterns, elementor

So for the past 9 hours, I have been trying to achieve the impossible as I Have finally fallen in love with Elementor Pro.
The dilemma is that I have tried over and over to use a pop up as The Tooltip for a Hotspot image
or find a way to have the pop up come up when the image is clicked on the hotspot icon

Please any help will greatly be welcome

I want to have the visitors Click on the Image (In the Hotspot and have them load the Pop up without leaving the page)

Comment: Please follow the answers and comments and mark answers accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Elementor PRO you have to create a popup in the theme builder part.
Once created it will be available in the link fields of the widgets (toothed wheel icon).
See the [Elementor documentation](https://elementor.com/help/how-do-i-create-my-first-popup/) for that.